# partialSubmit with graphicImage not working?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I have a simple page, implementing a password input field with strength analysis. I'm usign **Ice-faces 1.8.2**.

I set the **partialSubmit** property of password input field to display password strength:

```
<ice:inputSecret redisplay="true" partialSubmit="true" 
    id="password" value="#{beanreg.password}"/>
<ice:panelGroup>
     <ice:graphicImage id="imgstrength" url="/images/#{beanreg.strengthImage}"/>
     <ice:outputText id="pwdstrength" 
      value="#{beanreg.passwordStrength}"/> 
</ice:panelGroup>
<ice:inputSecret partialSubmit="true" 
    id="password2" value="#{beanreg.password2}"/>
```

When I leave the password input field, the `pwdstrength` component correctly update his value, but the `imgstrength` field doesn't change the image. The image get changed only when subsequently I leave the field `password2` or when I click anywhere in the form.

I tested the form both on Firefox3.6 and Chrome: same behaviour.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely cached by the browser. Add a query string with a timestamp so that the browser is forced to request it fresh new from the server.

```
<ice:graphicImage id="imgstrength" url="/images/#{beanreg.strengthImage}?#{now.time}"/>
```

Where `#{now}` is a request scoped managed bean of class [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>now</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.Date</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```